# .NET MVC3 - Url and Controller relation?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm rather new to ASP .NET MVC3.
I know that when I create my controllers through Visual Studio, they will respond to some URL. But where is defined which controller responds to which URL ?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `global.asax` file - the routing table is normally defined there.

This is the mapping between URLs and controllers/actions.

See the official [ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) for details.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but then:,why is it that I only see a registration for "Home" controller and none for my other controllers, not even for 'AccountController'.

Comment: And how does it know that controller = "Home" refers to the class "HomeController" ?

Comment: @user1103990 - Convention. It knows that it needs to add `Controller` to the passed in value and look for a type of that name.